# Argument 'meetupsController' is not a function, got undefined Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam newbie to Angular and express Frameworks.Iam developing a simple server which responds to the given route and show the value of variable which was declared in the controller.But there was an error such as the controller is not defined.Here the controller is stored in client/js/controllers folder for convenience
The code of the entire project is here

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name ="viewport" content ="width=device-width ,initial-scale =0">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Meetups View -->
    <div ng-controller="meetupsController">
        <h1>There are {{meetupsCount}} meetups</h1>
        <!-- <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="meetup in meetups">
                {{meetup.name}}
            </li>
        </ul> -->
        <!-- <form ng-submit="createMeetup()">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Meetup Name" ng-model="meetupName"></input>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form> -->
    </div>

    <!-- <a href="">Hello World</a> -->
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="/js/controllers/meetups-controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

meetups-controller.js

```
function meetupsController ($scope) {
    $scope.meetupsCount = 10;

    // $scope.meetups = [
 //     { name : "Meet 1"},
 //     { name : "Meet 2"},
 //     { name : "Meet 3"}
    // ]
    // $scope.createMeetup =  function () {
    //  $scope.meetups.push({ name : $scope.meetupsName});
    //  $scope.meetupsName = '';
    // }
}
```

main.js

```
// console.log("Hello from node");

//Express server

var express = require('express');
    app = express();

app.get('/' , function(req ,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
});

app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname +'/client/js'));

app.listen(3000 ,function () {
    console.log('Im Listening .... ');
});
```

The error log is here

```
angular.js:12520 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=meetupsController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at qb (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:22:131)
    at Qa (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:22:218)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:80:210
    at w (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:60:177)
    at D (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:61:30)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:105)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:122)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:122)
```

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: Where is Your app main module definition like `var app = angular.module("meetupsApp", []);` ?

Comment: Don't use `angular.min.js` in development; only in production. Use `angular.js` in development.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined an Angular app (`ng-app=""`) and haven't registered your controller in the angular app.

meetups-controller.js (add at the bottom of the file):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('meetupsController', meetupsController);
```

index.html (change):

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Answer (score 1):

this works in older versions of angular not the new one 
change your angular version to

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js" > </script>
```

**or define a module in js file for working with latest angular versions**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('meetupsController', meetupsController);


function meetupsController ($scope) {
    $scope.meetupsCount = 10;
}
```

**in html**

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

Comment: Using getters/setters is better: `angular.module('app',[])` and `angular.module('app').controller('meetupsController', meetupsController);`